# Function linear in its arguments

Tags: functions, terminology, kalman-filter

What does it mean to say that a function *is linear in [some of] its arguments*?

I tried to Google it and nothing came up.

Answer (score 1):

It could mean one of two things depending on the context. If your function is $f$, then it could mean:

1. $f(x+a) = f(x)+f(a)$

Or

2. $f(x+a) = f(x)+f(a)$ **and** $f(ax) = af(x)$.

Comment: the second condition can be expressed more succinctly as af(x)+f(y) = f(ax+y)

Comment: Most definitely.

Comment: Where "more succinctly" goes opposite way of "easier to understand", @charlotte.

Comment: I don't think so. Expressing it as two identities means the student needs to make the extra step of realizing that they can interact nicely.

Comment: For continuous functions of real variables, the statements 1. and 2. are equivalent.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Of course. Who knows what the real context is here though.. OP completely abandoned the post.